# Get maximum count of a value in a column

Tags: sql

If I have a simple database table of names like so:

```
--------------
| NAME       |
--------------
| Andrew     |
| Bill       |
| Andrew     |
| Claire     |
| Claire     |
| Andrew     |
--------------
```

Is it possible to run a query that would produce a tally of the names?  i.e.

```
-----------------------
| NAME       | COUNT  |
-----------------------
| Andrew     | 3      |
| Claire     | 2      |
| Bill       | 1      |
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want this to get the max:

```
    SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS c
      FROM TABLE
  GROUP BY Name
  ORDER BY c DESC
```